# SonarQube - Not able assign permission templates automatically to projects

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube Version : Enterprise Edition Version 8.4.2 (build 36762)

**Issue :**

Created a permission template sonarpoc-admin with project key pattern sonarpoc-.*
Created user/group sonarpoc-admin with admin level access and applied sonarpoc-* Project Key pattern so that if we login as a sonarpoc-admin, we should able to see any project which matches with sonarpoc-.* pattern

Created a permission template sonarpoc-dev with project key pattern sonarpoc-dev.*
Created user/group sonarpoc-dev_team and applied sonarpoc-dev.* Project Key pattern so that if we login as a sonarpoc-dev_team, we should able to see only projects which matches with sonarpoc-dev.* pattern

Created a permission template sonarpoc-test with project key pattern sonarpoc-test.*
Created user/group sonarpoc-test_team and applied sonarpoc-test.* Project Key pattern so that if we login as a sonarpoc-test_team, we should able to see only projects which matches with sonarpoc-test.* pattern.

but when I try scanning a project, none of the permissions templates are applied automatically and users sonarpoc-dev_team or sonarpoc-test_team cannot see there respective projects even with the project key pattern match. We can see projects only when we disable permission templates sonarpoc-dev, sonarpoc-test and use only sonarpoc-admin template with sonarpoc-admin as a user.(login)

**Just to clarify - Here is the expectation on scanning a new project with matching key pattern.**

Permission Template 1: sonarpoc-admin
Matching Project key Pattern: sonarpoc.*

Permission Template 2: sonarpoc-admin
Matching Project key Pattern: sonarpoc-dev.**

Permission Template 3: sonarpoc-admin
Matching Project key Pattern: sonarpoc-test.*

Scenario 1:
Scan a new project with matching project key pattern sonarpoc-dev.* (ex: sonarpoc-dev-devproject1)
Expectation is to have the Permission Template 1 & 2 assigned automatically on successful scan.

Scenario 2:
Scan a new project with matching project key pattern sonarpoc-test.* (ex: sonarpoc-test-testproject1)
Expectation is to have the Permission Template 1 & 3 assigned automatically on successful scan.

Scenario 3:
Scan a new project with matching project key pattern sonarpoc-.* (ex: sonarpoc-admin-adminproject1)

Expectation is to have the Permission Template 1 assigned automatically on successful scan.
With current setup, if we are configuring just the Permission template 1 alone, the new projects are being assigned automatically to that Permission template automatically upon successful scan. However when multiple permission templates are configured, they seems to have conflicts and permission templates are not assigned at all.

Comment: What is the source of authentication to sonarqube ? Is it LDAP or something ?

Comment: We created sonarQube local users/groups

Comment: Permission template is an initial permission set when a project matching defined project key is created, i.e. if you create a new project like _sonarpoc-dev-foo_, it should get the permissions set as specified in _sonarpoc-dev_. Templates are not dynamically applied, you need to explicitly set permissions on every project.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the Permission templates are not dynamically applied for all projects.

Just to clarify - Here is the expectation on scanning a new project with matching key pattern.
Permission Template 1: sonarpoc-admin
Matching Project key Pattern: sonarpoc

Permission Template 2: sonarpoc-admin
Matching Project key Pattern: sonarpoc-dev.**

Permission Template 3: sonarpoc-admin
Matching Project key Pattern: sonarpoc-test.* .... Continued in next comment section...

Comment: Scenario 1:
Scan a new project with matching project key pattern sonarpoc-dev.* (ex: sonarpoc-dev-devproject1)
Expectation is to have the Permission Template 1 & 2 assigned automatically on successful scan.

Scenario 2:
Scan a new project with matching project key pattern sonarpoc-test.* (ex: sonarpoc-test-testproject1)
Expectation is to have the Permission Template 1 & 3 assigned automatically on successful scan.

Scenario 3:
Scan a new project with matching project key pattern sonarpoc-.* (ex: sonarpoc-admin-adminproject1) .... Continued in next comment section.

Comment: Expectation is to have the Permission Template 1 assigned automatically on successful scan.
With current setup, if we are configuring just the Permission template 1 alone, the new projects are being assigned automatically to that Permission template automatically upon successful scan. However when multiple permission templates are configured, they seems to have conflicts and permission templates are not assigned at all.